# how to submit a form multi times with one button and open them in many tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder how to submit multi times my form to open many tabs with one button.
my code here :

```
<form action="?" id="form1" target="_blank">
  <a class="btn" href="javascript:;"  onclick="submit_form();return false;">Submit</a>
</form>
<script>
function submit_form() {
   for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
     document.form1.id.value = i;  // id is field to send data to server
     document.form1.submit();
   }
}
</script>
```

I want to click a.btn then submit one by one and open multi tabs.
But, form just submit the last id and just open one tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do it synchronously. You can try to use `setTimeout()` to put each submission into it's own "thread":

```
for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.form1.id.value = i;  // id is field to send data to server
    document.form1.submit();
  }, 0);
}
```

Maybe, if doesn't work, you can play with delay based on the `i`, e.g.

```
for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.form1.id.value = i;  // id is field to send data to server
    document.form1.submit();
  }, i * 100);
}
```

where every submission will be delayed by 100ms after the previous one

Comment: Why not use ajax to submit the form as many time as you want and open the tabs accordingly ?

Comment: Why do you ask me about that? I answer the question and I am given with this requirement. You are allowed to post your answer with any solution you want

Comment: i was trying to discuss if that could be better approach didnt knew u had a fight with your wife before reading my comment.

Comment: 1. you are assuming that ajax calls are possible when this is not known. In some legacy systems this is often impossible 2. you are assuming that the tabs that are about to be open make sense without posting the data directly to the page and finally 3. This is not about how it is better but how the OP wants it / what he is given with. As you can see there is nothing to discuss - your question should be pointed to the OP and not to me - I have no answers to the 3 points above. However the question statement is clear; the answer assumes nothing - it answers the original question